# I've got a formula for a generating function, but I can't seem to solve it

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm trying to solve the recurrence
$$
a_j = 0 \quad j \leq 0\\
a_1 = 1\\
\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n-k} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n-2k} - \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n-4k} \qquad n \geq 2
$$

The equation I got for the generating function$$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
$${A(x)}^2 = (2A(x^2) - A(x^4))(A(x)-A(-x)) + 2A(x^4)(A(x^2) - A(-x^2))$$
This level of hideousness is beyond my capabilities....and wolfram alpha's. How can I solve for A(x)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Do you think there is a closed form solution?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos getting that equation was hard as hell though....and I've tried deriving the lot(this made it worse), tried to use $$A(x)-A(-x)$$(also made it worse), substituting(I can't even grasp "what" to substitute from "what"). The equation won't budge

Comment: @CMPark can you tell us what the original problem was?  Is there a recurrence that you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @CMPark We don't know how you came to get the complex second formula here. Is it something that is generic for every such function as described in your first formula? Or is it derived from something else? Or is it a specific charcateristic of the function you have been given?

Comment: @Paul I'm really not sure

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, this was the recurrence $$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n-k} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n-2k} - \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n-4k}$$

Comment: @CMPark it looks like the formula requires $a_j$ for negative values of $j$.  Should all of those sums go from $0$ to $n/2$?  Also, how did you encounter this problem?  Is this a homework problem?  A research problem?  A difficult exam question?

Comment: @Martigan A(x) is the generating function for the recurrence mentioned above, and the equation in the post(which I probably got wrong) was made using cauchy's product. Or so I think...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I forgot to write(I can't use edit more than 2times), $$a_j = 0$$for all negative j, and a_1 = 1 it's..well...a challenge from a teacher(I'm a highschool student)

Comment: I've edited those details into your question.  Thanks for the details; that kind of context lets us know what level of work we should expect to be required (i.e. because this is your teacher's challenge problem, I can't immediately say that you're on the wrong track just because you encountered something complicated)

Comment: @CMPark am I correct in saying that $a_0 = 0$?  I don't think you specified

Comment: @Omnomnomnom oh yes....stupid me

Comment: @CMPark if you don't get an answer to this question in the next two days, tag me in another comment.  I'm interested in seeing this question answered, so I'd be happy to put down a bounty

Comment: There is an issue with you problem. 
Let's take your equation $E_n$:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n-k} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n-2k} - \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n-4k}$

And see what i going on for $n=2$

Then you have:

$a_0a_2+a_1a_1=2(a_0a_2+a_1a_0)-(a_0a_2+a_1a_{-2})$

If $a_j=0$ for $j \leq 0$, then we have

$a_1^2=0$, which is in contradiction with $a_1=1$...

Comment: @Martigan again, I've edited it wrongly, all the sums start from k=1.

Comment: @CMPark It does not change anything regarding the contradiction. I think you should write VERY precisely what the initial statement of the problem is, THEN explain what you tried and what are your issues.

Comment: @Martigan Thanks, I'll bear that in mind the next time I ask a question. Speaking of the problem, I think I've written something down wrongly. This was challenge given by a teacher, and I've copied the recurrence relation on a piece of paper, from which I typed the question. Sorry..